# Jquery/animate.css side menu disapearing when toggled more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

I have a pop out side menu which has the following trigger:

```
<a href="#" id="cmdAsideMenu" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-form-toggle" title="Open slidebar">
<i class="fa fa-outdent"></i>
</a>

<section id="asideMenu" class="aside-menu right">
 <div class="sidebar-content"></div>
</section>
```

This uses the following jQuery to add or remove the appropriate CSS classes to perform the animate in/out effect.

```
$(document).on("click", "#cmdAsideMenu, #btnHideAsideMenu, .navbar-toggle-aside-menu", function () {

        if ($("#asideMenu").is(":visible")) {
            $("#asideMenu").removeClass('animated bounceInRight');
            $("#asideMenu").addClass('animated bounceOutRight');
            $('#asideMenu').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $("#asideMenu").removeClass('animated bounceOutRight');
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#asideMenu").show().addClass('animated bounceInRight');
        }

        return false;
    });
```

This works fine the first time around. But if the trigger link (#cmdAsideMenu) is clicked again after showing and hiding the menu; it shows but dissapears again immediately after.

How can I ammend this code so that the menu can be open and closed repeatedly ok?

Cheers,
Danny

Answer (score 0):

Try refining your trigger conditional statement to be based off of classes rather than the `:visible` paremeter.  You would want to use classes because of their more exact nature, where as, CSS results can be sporadic.

So instead of `if ($("#asideMenu").is(":visible")) {`

use

`if ($('.animated').length < 1) {`.

Then, for the else conditional you would use `if ($('.animated').length > 0) {`.

Lastly, I assume that you are using the `.one()` method because there may be timing implications in your animation.  That is fine, but if you continue to run into issues you may want to consider the vanilla JavaScript methods `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` respectively.  Again, this is because the aftermentioned methods provide more absolute control and you can `clearInterval()` to **hard stop** the function.